# ASP stylesheet setting

Tags: html, css, asp-classic

How can I choose one of multiple stylesheets using ASP? Heres my ASP at the moment:

<%
T=Request.Cookies("THEME")
%>

It's in the head, there are two themes. I just need somone to show me how to do a conditional operator and if it's 1 then set a stylesheet. I could complete it from there

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB Script Syntax

```
<% 
   IF (T = "MyTheme") THEN
%>
    ///HTML Or Style Sheet Tag Here
<%
   ELSE
%>
   ///HTML OR Style Sheet Tag Here
<%
   END IF
%>
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated :D... ...So much simpler than JScript

Comment: Now it won't open... How do I get an ASP file to open with IE but formated as a HTML document? It was working earlier...

Comment: "It won't open" isnt enough information...do you receive an error?

Comment: No it opens like I want it to but just displays the source code.

Comment: are you opening the file directly using IE or are you hosting the file via IIS.   Classic ASP needs a server to host the source.

Comment: I'll do that now. It was opening earlier easily. I don't understand why it isn't anymore. I'll install IIS.

Comment: I don't suppose theres any language I can use with HTML that has a good cookie functionality and doesn't need installations and stuff?

Comment: That's what I was using originaly but the cookie code just got messy and out of hand. I'll attempt to understand the w3s' tutorial. I'm currently waiting for the IIS to enable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
    <%
    theme = request.cookies("theme")
    styleSheet = "<link rel=""stylesheet"" type=""text/css"" href="""
    if theme = "theme1" then
        styleSheet = styleSheet & "css/theme1.css"
    else
        styleSheet = styleSheet & "css/theme2.css"
    end if
    styleSheet = styleSheet & """ />"
    response.write(styleSheet)
    %>
</head>
```